# How may jsp page will get loaded into memory at a time?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Suppose my web application contain multiple jsp pages and other servlet and html.....files. So while am executing the web application how many jsp file at a time will loaded into memory? Anyone could you please help me on this....

Comment: Use a profiler, if you really want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That entirely depends on what servlet/JSP container you are using, so there is no general answer to your question.

Most servlet/JSP containers, for example Apache Tomcat, compile JSPs into servlets - when you access a JSP for the first time, Tomcat converts it into a servlet under the covers, which is then called to handle requests for the page.

Comment: Thanks Jesper for your reply, but even for Apache Tomcat at a time hom many jsp will get loaded into memory?Is it one or unlimited or it specifically depends on the container....

Comment: I don't know, that's an implementation detail of Tomcat. Why do you worry about this? Do you worry that you have too many JSPs and it's not going to work?

Answer (score 0):

Normally JSP is translated, compiled and loaded when first request is made, but smart containers do it automatically so that first request overhead is not there.

So this is totally dependent on servlet containers.

Comment: Hi Prasad,its correct but to be more clear.. lets say one application contains n numbers of jsp and m number of requests are coming to the server. So simply after the jsp converts into the servlet for that m number of request how it will serve them. Whether all n number of jsps(converted servlet) will present in memory to serve m number of request....??

Comment: @Bijay, for every request, a new thread will be created and it will access the same servlet instance and call the service method. There will be only one servlet and multiple threads access the same instance

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially dependent on the servlet container you're using (Jetty, Tomcat), but usually each JSP will get compiled and loaded when it's first used (or beforehand, if you use load-on-startup) and then will stay loaded. The JSP file itself isn't "loaded" as such; it's used as a template to create a handler method that gets called whenever you need to use it to generate output.

Comment: Hi Chrylis,its correct but to be more clear.. lets say one application contains n numbers of jsp and m number of requests are coming to the server. So simply after the jsp converts into the servlet for that m number of request how it will serve them. Whether all n number of jsps(converted servlet) will present in memory to serve m number of request....??

Comment: @Bijay Your question with the `n` and `m` isn't clear. At runtime, a JSP gets converted into a servlet, and then each request that goes to that JSP for output just calls the rendering method on that servlet. You don't have separate copies of the JSP for each request.